# How to check if string only contains set of characters in Rust?

Tags: rust, text-processing

What is the idiomatic way in Rust to check if a string only contains a certain set of characters?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'd use `all` to check that all characters are alphanumeric.

```
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Böb");
    println!("{}", name.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric));
}
```

- [`chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) returns an iterator of characters.
- [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) returns true if the function is true for all elements of the iterator.
- [`is_alphanumeric`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_alphanumeric) checks if its alphanumeric.

For arbitrary character sets you can pass whatever function or code block you like to `all`.

Interestingly, [the corresponding methods on `str` were explicitly removed for subtle Unicode reasons](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49657).

Answer (score 8):

There is [is_alphanumeric()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_alphanumeric):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", "abcd".chars().all(|x| x.is_alphanumeric()));
}
```

Comment: `s.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric)` also works in this case.

Comment: And for clarity, the "generic" version is to change the predicate in `all`.