# How can I check if a &str consists of only a given slice of chars?

Tags: rust

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn shifter(s: &str) -> usize {
    s.split(' ')
     .unique()
     .map(|x| x.chars().
}
```

Im trying to finish up the task to calculate how many "shifter words" a given &str contains without any duplicates. "shifter word" is one that consist only of "H", "I", "N", "O", "S", "X", "Z", "M" and "W".

```
shifter("SOS IN THE HOME") == 2 // shifter words are "SOS" and "IN"
shifter("WHO IS SHIFTER AND WHO IS NO") == 3 // shifter words are "WHO", "IS", "NO"
shifter("TASK") == 0 // no shifter words
shifter("") == 0 // no shifter words in empty string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting it all together from:

- [How to check if a string contains a substring in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794974/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-rust)
- [How to check if string only contains set of characters in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391548/how-to-check-if-string-only-contains-set-of-characters-in-rust)

```
fn shifter(s: &str) -> usize {
    s.split(' ')
        .unique()
        .filter(|x| !x.is_empty() && x.chars().all(|c| "HINOSXZMW".contains(c)))
        .count()
}
```

The `is_empty()` is there because `all()` returns true for an empty collection.

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=646e9b41a2d12d77f20ab3814d8644a9).

Comment: Swapping `filter` and `unique` seems like an obvious improvement

Answer (score 4):

You can test if every element matches a given predicate by using [`Iterator::all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) and [`str::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains).

```rust
"SOS".chars().all(|c| "HINOSXZMW".contains(c)); // true
```

Note that there's also [`slice::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains), so the following would work as well:

```rust
let letters = ['H', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'X', 'Z', 'M', 'W'];

"SOS".chars().all(|c| letters.contains(&c)); // true
```